# ckeditor4 source always adds extra html classes and elements

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I am using ckeditor 4 but each time i write something and click source tool, it adds extra classes and html tags that i dont need. How do i remove this?

This are my screenshots

input version
[image: initial input]

source version
[image: source version]

expected source
[image: expected version]

This is my config.js

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config )
{

  config.filebrowserBrowseUrl = "/ckeditor/attachment_files";
  config.filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl = "/ckeditor/attachment_files";
  config.filebrowserFlashUploadUrl = "/ckeditor/attachment_files";
  config.filebrowserImageBrowseLinkUrl = "/ckeditor/pictures";
  config.filebrowserImageBrowseUrl = "/ckeditor/pictures";
  config.filebrowserImageUploadUrl = "/ckeditor/pictures?";
  config.filebrowserUploadUrl = "/ckeditor/attachment_files";
  config.allowedContent = true;
  config.removeDialogTabs = 'link:upload;image:Upload;image:advanced';


    config.toolbar = [
        { name: 'clipboard',   groups: [ 'clipboard', 'undo' ], items: ['Paste', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord', '-', 'Undo', 'Redo' ] },
        { name: 'links', items: [ 'Link', 'Unlink']  },
        { name: 'insert', items: [ 'Image', 'Table' ] },
        { name: 'forms' },
        { name: 'tools' },
        { name: 'document',    groups: [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ], items: [ 'Source']  },
        { name: 'others' },
        '/',
        { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ], items: [ 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'Subscript', 'Superscript', '-', 'RemoveFormat' ] },
        { name: 'paragraph',   groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi' ], items: [ 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Outdent', 'Indent', '-', 'Blockquote', '-', 'JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock' ] },
        { name: 'styles', items: [ 'Styles', 'Format', 'Font', 'FontSize' ] },
        { name: 'colors', items: [ 'TextColor', 'BGColor' ] },
        { name: 'about' }
    ];

};
```

This is my ckeditor.rb

```
Ckeditor.setup do |config|

  require 'ckeditor/orm/active_record'
  config.cdn_url = "//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.7.1/standard/ckeditor.js"
  config.js_config_url = 'ckeditor/config.js'
end
```

Not sure what i am doing wrong here but why is the formatting not working properly for source version.

Thanks

Comment: CKEditor doesn't add anything like that in source mode. I would rather suspect some third-party script. You should look for a code which adds `docs-internal-guid`. Another possibility is that browser adds these attributes to HTML. None of browsers is doing that by default however you might have some third-party browser plugin installed which modifies your HTML. In such a case disabling it might be the solution.

Comment: If for some reason browser would be doing that by default then you should enable ACF. At the moment you have set `config.allowedContent = true;` which allows everything including garbage HTML to be entered into the editor. Once you have it enabled you can configure it to allow extra content with https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_config.html#cfg-extraAllowedContent and disallow extra things which CKEditor doesn't block by default with https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_config.html#cfg-disallowedContent.